# Visual Studio Code requires an older version of .NET framework to be installed, but version is no longer supported?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, smartsheet-api

I made a clone on an existing repo on GitHub and tried running the script on Visual Studio Code. I had installed .NET 7.0 core and Git in order to run the code. The code I am testing on runs on C#.

However, the error message returns me with the exact following message
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1229,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2 were not found.

I then downloaded .NET Framework 4.5.2 and restart Visual Studio Code. However, it returns with more error messages on the code. The code is fine as I had cloned this repository from the sample project for SmartSheets API.

Comment: what is the error after installing .net 4.5.2 ? and can you share a link? what have you downloaded exactly?

Comment: hi vivek nuna, there are multiple error messages with 
"The type or namespace name 'Smartsheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

I cloned this repository https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet.

Comment: VS Code doesn't require any .NET Framework or .NET Core version, unless you want to edit a .NET Framework project. .NET Framework 4.5.2 is out of support. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2 but there's no real reason to install anything less than the latest version, 4.8. .NET 7 is *.NET Core 7*

Comment: @clayton55 if you want to compile a .NET Framework project you need to install the .NET Framework SDK. You don't need VS Code to compile, only to edit.

Comment: hi Panagiotis Kanavos, is there a way to run the code without installing the .NET Framework SDK? i tried Run without Debugging but VS automatically suggests me to download the .NET Frameworks

Comment: FYI, in case it's helpful -- there seems to be a related issue logged in the GitHub repo you're using: https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet/issues/1 -- comment says `The current C# SDK requires the .NET 4.5.2 (or above) framework.`. You may want to log your own issue there within the GitHub repo, to see if someone from Smartsheet can help.